# SonarQube 5.2 - where is Libraries / dependencies page?

Tags: sonarqube

In the older version of Sonar, there was a Dependencies or 'Library cartography' page, but I can't seem to find it in 5.2 - anyone know where it might be?

http://www.sonarqube.org/sonar-2-1-in-screenshots/

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Managing+Libraries

The reason/usecase was to have a single location when there may be a library (commons logging like the example, or commons collections when there is a vulnerability for example) to find all projects that contain that dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was dropped with 5.2

[Drop the Design related services and metrics](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6553)

Comment: very sad face, but thanks for the specific reference