# Sonarqube dependencies page alternative?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, libraries

That feature was very useful for us, but after upgrade sonar 5.1 to 5.6 we have missed it.

Reading this topic : [Sonarqube dependency feature missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923850/sonarqube-5-2-where-is-libraries-dependencies-page) i want to ask if you know a similar alternative to check dependency libraries for a proyect.

We was using this feature for check 3PPs dependency shared between projects and check what other projects was using the same 3pp.

Do you know a similar tool?

Comment: For a specific language?

Comment: We need it for java dependencies (jar files) because our sonarqube instance only can analyze java code.